# OData Filter by an M-M relationship

Tags: odata, odata-v4

Is it possible to filter in odata by the linked entities in an M-M relationship where it must contain all of the second, but allow extras?

Suppose I've got:
Student
StudentClass
Class
and I want to find all students where their enrolment includes the classes (101, 102, 103)

Comment: You should include the URL or calling syntax to attract an answer that you will be able to readily consume. The best we can do with this information is assume the URL routes your API uses and provide theoretical responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, OData v4 provides 2 [Lambda Operators](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc444868730) that evaluate a Boolean expression on a collection. These are `Any` and `All`, where `Any` returns the record if *atleast one* of the child entries matches the criteria, and `All` requires *all* of the child records to match.

In your case we can use `Any`:

> **5.1.1.10.1 any**
> The `any` operator applies a Boolean expression to each member of a collection and returns true if the expression is true for any member of the collection, otherwise it returns false. The `any` operator without an argument returns true if the collection is not empty.
>
> Example 79: all Orders that have any Items with a Quantity greater than 100
>
> `http://host/service/Orders?$filter=Items/any(d:d/Quantity gt 100)`

however we can't pass through an array or list of values to compare against so we have to break this query down into an `Any` expression for each value and `AND` them together.
This sounds counter intuitive but the following simple query where we use `OR` inside a *single* `Any` results in matches where the Student has *one or more* of the classes (101,102,103) but not neccessarily *all* of them:

```
http://host/service/Students?$filter=Enrollments/Any(e:e/Class/Code eq '101' or e/Class/Code eq '102' or e/Class/Code eq '103')
```

if they must be enrolled in *atleast **all of** 101,102,103* then we must `AND` the results of a separate `Any` operator for each of the classes, below is the 3 separate queries for each class and a final query that `AND`s them together:

```
http://host/service/Students?$filter=Enrollments/Any(e:e/Class/Code eq '101')
http://host/service/Students?$filter=Enrollments/Any(e:e/Class/Code eq '102')
http://host/service/Students?$filter=Enrollments/Any(e:e/Class/Code eq '103')

http://host/service/Students?$filter=Enrollments/Any(e:e/Class/Code eq '101') AND Enrollments/Any(e:e/Class/Code eq '102') AND Enrollments/Any(e:e/Class/Code eq '103')
```

*These queries assume:

there is a navigation property on the `Student` record called `Enrollments` that links the `Student` to **a collection** of `StudentClass` records,

`StudentClass` has a navigation property called 'Class' that links it to **a single** `Class` record,

the class codes (**101**,**102**,**103**) are stored in a **string** property on the `Class` record called `Code`*

> **NOTE:** Different providers support these Lambda operators to different extents, you should check with your vendor/developer if you have have complex needs like support for nesting expressions with `Any` or `All` or if the simplest queries are not resolving as you expect.

This query does not specifically request that the `Enrollments` or the `Class` records be included in the results, it should only return a list of `Students` unless there is server-side configuration or logic to `$expand` these navigation properties by default.

---

While not needed by OP, if you are expanding these same object graphs (that you are filtering by), it is important to point out that using the `Any` operator in the root `$filter` query option will not apply filtering to the expanded child collection. If you wanted to return *ONLY* the child records that matched the expression you would need to implement a `$filter` expression within the `$expand` query option, *in addition to* the `Any` operator in the root `$filter` query option.

The reverse is also true, simply using the `$filter` within the `$expand` query option will not prevent the top level `Student` from being returned if they were only enrolled in other classes, it wouldn't return any classes because they didn't match the criteria, but it would still return the `Student` record.

For this reason, when using `$filter` nested inside `$expand` it is *very common* to include an `Any` or `All` operator in the `$filter` query option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation, Chris. I've searched the web for a long time to prove the same idea that you expressed really well. About combining multiple `any/` clauses with `AND` if you need to match the entity collection with an array of values.
Docs for OData v4 are lacking for these kind of examples

Comment: After writing front ends against OData services for a few years now @EugeneZakharov I find myself using these operators less and less. It's great the OData has this flexibility and my front end guys can rapidly prototype against what is effectivly an open API, but most production facing code gets optimised into custom actions and functions. So while the documentation is a little lacking I feel that is becuase there is a lack of demand and leadership in the community to fill the gaps. Keep posting query requests in SO and we'll find the answer for you!

Comment: I should update this post, OData now has extensive support for the IN operator which further simplifies this comparison